# Python unicode fails 3.4.3

Tags: python, unicode

I'm new here, both in programming and in Python.Am tried to do a fun joculete but it came out too fine.I not really know exactly what to do with unicode .. I do not know how to defend the euro symbol € in the program(Python 3.4.3):

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

valoare = ''

bani = 1000

#Numele jucatorului
def Nume():
    name = input("Cum te numesti?: ")
    clear()

    if (name.isalpha() == True):
        print('Bun venit ', name ,'!', sep = '')
    else:
        print('Numele tau nu este valid! Mai alege-l odata!')
        Nume()  
Nume()

#Jucatorul alege valuta cu care v-a juca:
def Valuta():
    valutaCurenta = int(input('Alege 1 pentru euro\nAlege 2 pentru dolar: '))

    euro = u"\u20ac"

    global valoare

    if (valutaCurenta == 1):
       clear()
       valoare = euro
       print('Ai ales EURO ca valuta!')
    elif (valutaCurenta == 2):
        clear()
        valoare = '$'
        print('Ai ales DOLAR ca valuta!')
    else:
        clear()
        print('Alege 1 sau 2!')
        Valuta()
Valuta()

#Continuarea jocului
continuare = input('Apasa ENTER pentru a continua jocul!')

#Meniu
def Meniu():
    print ('Alege 1 pentru a cumpara o mingie in valoare de 10', valoare ,'\nAlege 2 pentru a muncii si pentru a obtine 20', valoare ,' pe ora\nAlege 3 pentru a vedea banii tai', sep = '')
    numarCumparat = int(input(': '))    
    global bani

    #Meniu
    if (numarCumparat == 1):
        clear()
        bani -= 10
        print('Ai cumparat o mingie!')
        print('Acuma mai ai:', bani ,'$',sep = '')
        Meniu()     
    elif (numarCumparat == 3):
        clear()
        print('Ai ', bani , '$', sep = '')
        Meniu()         
    elif (numarCumparat == 2):
        clear()
        ore = int(input('Cate ore vrei sa muncesti?: '))
        clear()
    else:
        clear()
        print ('Am zis sa alegi 1,2 sau 3!')
        Meniu()

    #Verifica ca ore <= 10 altfel daca ore > 10 atunci nu poti munci!   
    if (ore <= 10):
        bani += ore * 20
        print('Dupa o munca de ', ore , ' ore ai primit:', ore * 20 , '$!', sep = '')
        print('Acuma ai in total:', bani ,'$',sep = '')
        Meniu()
    else:
        print('Nu poti muncii mai mult de 10 ore!')
        Meniu()     
clear()
Meniu()
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you wondering how to print the Euro symbol? You managed to type it here in your question just fine. What happens when you add that to your code?

Comment: I see you defined the Euro symbol by the Unicode codepoint as `euro = u"\u20ac"`. The `u` prefix is redundant in Python 3, but what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: In the console gives me error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' can't codec encode character '\ u20ac' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Ah, you have a *printing problem*. Your console cannot handle the Euro symbol. Python is doing just fine.